# adding before_helpers and helper_methods to devise controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a set of before_helpers and helper_methods that apply to some controllers, including all devise controllers.

What would be the preferred way to declare those before filters?

I tried [this article](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/16/revisited-adding-filters-to-stock-devise-controllers/) with no success (got an error `sessions_controller.rb to define Devise::SessionsController (LoadError)`). And If I re do all the controllers I need to copy the same code again from the gem which looks repetitive.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `before_filter` in your `application_controller.rb` and check whether `params[:controller]` is the name of a Devise controller:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :check_if_devise

    private

    def check_if_devise
        if ['confirmations', 'omniauth_callbacks', 'passwords', 'registrations', 'sessions', 'unlocks'].include? params[:controller]
            # logic for before_filter
        end
    end
end
```

**Update:**

Alternatively, if you want to keep you existing `before_filter` separate from the `check_if_devise` logic, you can remove the existing function from `before_filter` and invoke it only if the conditional logic of `check_if_devise` passes:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :check_if_devise

    private

    def check_if_devise
        if ['confirmations', 'omniauth_callbacks', 'passwords', 'registrations', 'sessions', 'unlocks'].include? params[:controller]
            function_to_run
        end
    end

    def function_to_run
        # code goes here
    end
end
```

Placing this within `application_controller.rb` will ensure that the `before_filter` is run for a Devise controllers. For other, individual one-off controllers, you can invoke `function_to_run` as a `before_filter`:

```
# app/controller/random_controller.rb
class RandomController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :function_to_run

end
```

Comment: The before_filter logic is already defined separated and its shared across other controllers so adding logic on "logic for before_filter" will seem repetitive. Any way to keep the before filter separated?

Comment: Rather than defining the logic within the `check_if_devise` conditional, you can define a function containing that logic, then invoke it however you see fit. See my update.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I get `undefined local variable or method 'current_site'` when visiting devise login page. current_site is a `helper_method` called inside the `check_if_devise` method.

Comment: You can fix that by defining `current_site` inside `application_controller.rb`. The upside of doing this is that it'll be available for use inside _any_ of your controllers.

Comment: Since I'm caching the actions, the idea is to call these methods after the cache action and before in the non-cached actions. That's why I'm trying to avoid it directly globally.

Comment: Or maybe I should set them global are use skip filter for the cached actions and call before_helpers them again below the cache? Seems a bit nasty.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd do. Everything should run precisely the same way as they would if you were defining functions within individual controllers, the upside being that your functions will enjoy global availability.

Comment: BTW, if you were explicitly seeking to avoid global definitions, you should probably have cited the requirement in your question.

Comment: My fault. So you mean you defined them globally and eventually use skip before filters even if you call it again below the cache action?

Comment: If that's the flow you're looking to implement, I think that's the correct way about it. Not sure whether you could refactor it to work any better, quite frankly.